# Могут ли боты в приватных канал коммуницировать между собой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Вот пример кода первого бота (получателя):

```
if message.text == "Привет, как оно?":
    bot.send_message(-539928766, "Неплохо, сам как?")
```

И второй бот (отправитель):

```
def send_message():
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook('quest.xls', formatting_info=True) #Цитаты бота 2
    sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
    for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    rand = int(random.randint(0, rownum))
    row = sheet.row_values(rand)
    bot.send_message(-539928766, row)
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(send_message)
```

Вопрос: может бот 1 принимать сообщения бота 2 и отвечать на них? Если да, то можете скинуть пример кода. Еесли останутся вопросы по поводу кода, отвечу. Использовал модули Telebot, scedule и  xlrd

Comment: Думаю ничего невозможного тут нет, `is_bot` cвойство по которому можно отличить бота от обычного пользователя, ну и разумеется в сообщении узнать его `id` чтобы дополнительно указать с каким ботом стоит общаться

Comment: Боты не могут общаться между собой, никаких примеров кода тут не будет, к сожалению

Comment: ОК а можете навести пример кода, Danii Loban?